# Custom TCA validations in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

How do I create a custom validation for a TCA field? We want to check the input of a textfield with an AJAX-request. So it should be done with JS. If I check the FormEngineValidation.js it seems there is no option for using custom validators.

Is that right? Or did I miss something?

Version: TYPO3 CMS 7LTS

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47530374/4671932

Answer (score 1):

The 'eval' api of FormEngine is still rather ugly.

ext:styleguide brings an example for input_21 that adds some JS magic using returnFieldJS(), this may or may not be enough for your use case.

https://github.com/TYPO3/styleguide/blob/master/Classes/UserFunctions/FormEngine/TypeInput21Eval.php