# Typo3 extension: Prevent the BE user to save a record if he made an undesired input in a field

Tags: typo3

Basically I try to prevent the BE user to input something wrong. Thatfore i use an external evaluation class (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/8-dev/ColumnsConfig/Type/Input.html).

Now my problem is: The function i implemented changes the input and sets the change for the property

```
public function evaluateFieldValue($value, $is_in, &$set)
{
  if(...){
  $value = 'Wrong input';
  }
  return $value;
}
```

but that's not what i'm aiming for. I want the BE user to get an error message window (like 'wrong input') on saving the record. How do i do that?

Comment: check `returnFieldJS` method

Comment: That's what i'm doing. The function is from my own eval.php... And it works, just not the way i want it to. Again: I want an error message in the BE, not change the value to something else if the input is undesired. But the Typo3 documentation does only provide this, nothing else. But how should i implement what i'm aiming for?

Comment: from docs > You can supply own form evaluations in an extension by creating a class with three functions, one which returns the JavaScript code for client side validation called `returnFieldJS()` and two for the server side: deevaluateFieldValue() called when opening the record and evaluateFieldValue() called for validation when saving the record:

Comment: I implemented the evaluateFieldValue(), that's basically what i posted above. So basically i need to do this with JavaScript code?

Comment: It seems that `vendor/typo3/cms/typo3/sysext/backend/Resources/Public/JavaScript/FormEngineValidation.js` `FormEngineValidation.processValue` is responsible for frontend valdiation. If somehow to extend it.

Answer (score 2):

I will give an entry path, not a full solution.

`ext_localconf.php`

```
$signalSlotDispatcher = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\SignalSlot\\Dispatcher');
$signalSlotDispatcher->connect(
    'TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Controller\EditDocumentController', 'initAfter',
    'YourVendor\YourExtension\Hooks\Backend\EditDocSlot', 'initAfter');
```

`YourVendor\YourExtension\Hooks\Backend\EditDocSlot.php`

```
namespace YourVendor\YourExtension\Hooks\Backend;

use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Controller\EditDocumentController;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility;

class EditDocSlot
{
    /**
     *
     * @param EditDocumentController $ref
     */
    public function initAfter(EditDocumentController $ref)
    {
        /** @var PageRenderer $pageRenderer */
        $pageRenderer = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer::class);
        $pageRenderer->addJsFile(ExtensionManagementUtility::extRelPath('your_extension') . 'Resources/Public/JavaScript/FormEngineValidation.js');
    }
}
```

`your_extension/Resources/Public/JavaScript/FormEngineValidation.js`

```
require(['jquery', "TYPO3/CMS/Backend/FormEngineValidation"], function ($, FormEngineValidation) {
    // extend FormEngineValidation
    // check FormEngineValidation.processValue and
    // check FormEngineValidation.validateField
    // and create a new eval ???!!! :)
});
```

Some javascript patching info
http://me.dt.in.th/page/JavaScript-override/

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. It'll take some time for me to get this working because i have absolutely no experience with javascript, but i really appreciate it. At least now i have a clear direction.

Comment: Check last line in answer for Javascript patching info. Also read the code of original `FormEngineValidation`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of **$set** in the function **evaluateFieldValue** to false if you don't want the new value to be saved.

For an **error message** you can use [TYPO3 Flash messages](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/FlashMessages/Index.html). This will output a message in the backend (red for ERROR, yellow for warning and green for OK). This is the standard way of showing messages in the TYPO3 backend.

This example does not accept the String "aaa", it will be discarded on saving and an error message will be displayed.

```php
/**
 * Server-side validation/evaluation on saving the record
 *
 * @param string $value The field value to be evaluated
 * @param string $is_in The "is_in" value of the field configuration from TCA
 * @param bool $set Boolean defining if the value is written to the database or not.
 * @return string Evaluated field value
 */
public function evaluateFieldValue($value, $is_in, &$set)
{    
    if ("aaa" === $value) {
        // input is to be discarded!
        $this->flashMessage("evaluateFieldValue", 
            "wrong input", 
            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage::ERROR);
        $set = False;
    }
    return $value;
}

function flashMessage($messagetitle, $messagetext, $severity=\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage::ERROR)
{
    $message = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage::class,
        $messagetext,
        $messagetitle, 
        $severity, 
        true 
   );

   $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
       \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager::class);
   $flashMessageService = $objectManager->get(
           \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessageService::class);
   $messageQueue = $flashMessageService->getMessageQueueByIdentifier();
   $messageQueue->addMessage($message);
}
```

Comment: The JavaScript solution is probably a good way to go, but I wanted to show an alternative solution using just PHP/TYPO3.